# Sqoop works through bash, but doesn't work through oozie

Tags: bash, sqoop, oozie

I have a shell script

```
  sqoop import \
  -Dmapreduce.job.queuename=adhoc \
  --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:secret@//secret \
  --query "a select"  \
  --target-dir /apps/hive/warehouse/data.db/fair_usage \
  --delete-target-dir \
  -m 1 \
  --fields-terminated-by '\t'
```

It works when I put it in sh file and run it. But when I try to run as a oozie action it fails. I tried using bash action and sqoop action both. This is Sqoop action. I also tried running sqoop with `<command>import....</command>` tag.

```
  <action name="export_table" cred="hv_cred">
    <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
      <job-tracker>${JOB_TRACKER}</job-tracker>
      <name-node>${NAME_NODE}</name-node>
      <configuration>
        <property>
          <name>mapred.task.timeout</name>
          <value>600000</value>
        </property>
      </configuration>
        <arg>import</arg>
        <arg>-Dmapreduce.job.queuename=adhoc</arg>
        <arg>--connect</arg>
        <arg>jdbc:oracle:thin:secret@//secret</arg>
        <arg>--query</arg>
        <arg>"a select"</arg>
        <arg>--target-dir</arg>
        <arg>/apps/hive/warehouse/data.db/fair_usage</arg>
        <arg>--delete-target-dir</arg>
        <arg>-m</arg>
        <arg>1</arg>
        <arg>--fields-terminated-by</arg>
        <arg>'\t'</arg>
    </sqoop>
    <ok to="END"/>
    <error to="KILL"/>
  </action>
```

The error I get is `Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellMain], exit code [1]` for bash and  `[org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain], exit code [1]` for sqoop.

Which doesn't tell me anything. When I view the logs, I can't find anything useful. Stderr has barely 30 rows and no errors. Syslog is longer, but no errors either.

After some time something new appeared

```
Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143
```

Edit

I tried running the script through a shell action again. It worked. The sh hasn't changed so I probably made a mistake in the workflow file. I haven't saved the old version of it, so can't say what that mistake was.

Shell action

```
  <action name='export_table'>
    <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
      <job-tracker>${JOB_TRACKER}</job-tracker>
      <name-node>${NAME_NODE}</name-node>
      <configuration>
        <property>
          <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
          <value>${QUEUE_NAME}</value>
        </property>
      </configuration>
      <exec>bash/export_table.sh</exec>
      <file>bash/export_table.sh#export_table.sh</file>
    </shell>
    <ok to="END"/>
    <error to="KILL"/>
  </action>
```

Still don't know why sqoop action doesn't work

EDIT2

A few months passed and I take my words back. Fecking sqoop. Same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had nothing to do with the workflow or the sqoop script itself, but rather some inner mechanics I'm not aware of. Missing libs maybe?

When I run the script in terminal, a java class is generated. This class seems to describe how the hive table is parsed to oracle table or smth. When I start oozie I need to add this autogenerated file to the root directory(the one with coordinator and workflow). If I don't oozie fails. The damn thing won't even give any  errors(

Anyway, after adding the java class to root, I can run the sqoop from a shell action. Sqoop action still doesn't work. Another thing I noticed, the shell action will execute if in sqoop I use

```
--export-dir /apps/hive/warehouse/db.db/table/
```

But if I try

```
--hcatalog-database db \
--hcatalog-table table \
```

in shell, it will fail anyway. It probably tries to add some libraries to class path and can't or smth.

Answer (score 0):

Quotes are syntactical in bash are not passed as argument literal

```
<arg>a select</arg>
...
<arg>\t</arg>
```

EDIT: after opening documentation https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.0/DG_SqoopActionExtension.html

first argument may be the command instead of first `<arg>`

```
 <command>import</command>
```

Comment: I've read the documentation. On that page there are 2 examples. One of them uses `<command>` and the other `<arg>` tags. They don't mix. I've tried just in case, but got an error.

Comment: on which operating system is it running?

Comment: 2.6.32-504.12.2.el6.x86_64 GNU/Linux